# How to check if caller still exist in task callback

Tags: c++, multithreading, callback

A very common scenario for a thread's callback is to inform the caller that it has finished his job. Here's the minimal example:

```
class task
{
public:
    void operator()(std::function<void()>&& callback)
    {
        std::thread t
        {
            [c = std::move(callback)]{
                std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{100});
                c();
            }
        };
        t.detach();
    }
};

class processor
{
public:
    void new_task()
    {
        auto& t = tasks.emplace_back();
        t([this]{ if (true/*this object still alives*/) finish_callback(); });
    }
    
private:
    void finish_callback()
    {
        // ...
    }
    
private:
    std::vector<task> tasks;
};
```

In such scenario, we have to support the case when the child task overlives the parent/caller. Is there any common design pattern that allows us to do this?

Theoretically, we may use `shared_ptr` + `enable_shared_from_this` + `weak_ptr` trio in such case, but this forces us to always store the parent object on the heap under `shared_ptr`. I would rather like to not have such a limitation.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to "given a pointer `p`, determine whether it's dangling". Not generally possible in C++.

Comment: Oh, and your program will be terminated at the end of `task::operator()`, when `t` goes out of scope without being joined or detached.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik your statement is not correct in 2 ways: (1) it is not equivalent, you don't even have to use pointers to solve this problem; (2) checking if pointer is dangling is possible, if you implement it yourself - `weak_ptr` is a class designed specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Yes, your suggested solution with `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` is vialbe - but didn't you say that you want to avoid it? As to (1) - the lambda does capture a pointer, `this`; and you wish to determine whether the captured copy of that pointer has become dangling.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik this is the example code, and it can of course be modified to achieve supposed behavior. Capturing `weak_ptr` is an option but, as I noticed, it is not ideal resolution. I am searching for a better one.

Comment: How about this. Instead of allocating `processor` itself on the heap, you can allocate something - anything , e.g. a single `char` - on the heap and have `processor` hold it in a `shared_ptr` member. Have the lambda capture a `weak_ptr` to it. When `processor` is destroyed, it will destroy the heap-based indicator, and the lambda would notice that.

Comment: Besides the lifetime issue, you also need to deal with a race condition - as you are checking whether `processor` is alive and then calling a method on it, that `processor` instance might be in the process of being destroyed.